# Copying Tables from a Website

Tags: microsoft-excel, internet-explorer, html

I have difficulty making an Excel-readable file from a table on a Website.
The problems very specific to my question are:

1. I have to use IE 7 to access the site.
2. Excel is installed in another computer.
3. The site does not let me view the HTML of the table.

Normally, I would simply select the table I want and drag and drop it to Excel.  Or, I would view the page source and copy the HTML data.  Both do not work in this case.

Is there any handy tool out there?

Comment: Can you explain why yo have to use IE7?

Comment: It has to be IE in order to access; electronic certificate and so on.  I don't know if I can upgrade IE without much trouble with the site.

Comment: I don't understand, the point that `site does not let me view the HTML of the table`, can you elaborate, is it a flash based site or something like that ?

Comment: Are you able to copy and paste the table data into a text file?

Comment: @Lamb "View page source" for the page where the table is on does not get table.  It only show JavaScript or something.  Yes, I can copy and paste the table into a text file but a lot of cells in the wrong columns.

Comment: Actually, I can copy and paste the table into a vBulletin-powered forum.  I can take out the table coded in vBulletin codes.  I would switch to another computer, post the table in the edit post window of the forum , drag and drop the preview into Excel.  It's really a big trouble.

Comment: (If your situation permits) It would be easier for someone to help if you can provide the link to the page.

Comment: It's a banking service, so no can do.

Comment: In Excel, you can have it directly import tables from a web page. From the data ribbon, you can select "From Web". It will allow you to use a embedded instance of IE to access/configure your site. Once your in, you can select the table(s) you want it to import.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this, and I don't have access to IE7 anymore....
But try `right click` on the page, and then use the `Export to Microsoft Excel` function.